# Is it possible to use the p5.js library in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, p5.js

I'm trying to access the p5.js library from google app script. Below is my the doGet() function I've tried. Am I doing it wrong? Or is this library inaccessible when using apps script?

```
function doGet() { eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js', Object).getContentText());

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

I've also tried updating the code by removing the Object parameter like this:

```
    function doGet() {
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js').getContentText());
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
    }
```

But I still get an error.

SyntaxError: Missing name after . operator.

UPDATE:
I tried Mario's code from below. It fixed the first error. But now I'm trying to create a canvas, and all I see is a blank page. No errors listed. Here's how the code looks now.

doget.gs

```
function doGet() {
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("demo");
   return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
}
```

sketch.gs

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,600);
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
}
```

demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.gs"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? Do you get an error message?

Comment: it says, "bad value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must create a new file and put all your HTML code with the javascript you want to use.

demo.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
    <?!= include('sketch'); ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

sketch.html

```
<script>
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,600);
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
}
</script>
```

Then in your Appsscript file code.gs. This create a mix of Google Apps Script code and HTML to produce dynamic pages

```
function doGet() {
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("demo");
   return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Here is the Google Documentation of HTML Service
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Please explain what this code does and why it's the correct answer instead of just dumping unexplained code.

Comment: Mario's code fixed the first error. But now I just see a blank page. No canvas. I updated the code in my original post to show what I have so far. It doesn't return any errors. Only a blank screen.

Comment: Wow! That makes perfect sense! Thanks, Mario! You're the man!